# Time Doctor on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04

I have just installed ubuntu 18.04 and I tried to install timedoctor app but I 'm getting some errors which releated to ubuntu packages. These libcv2.4, ... I cannot install timedoctor on ubuntu 18.04.

### This is  the Error

```
dpkg -i Downloads/timedoctorlite_2.3.49-15ubuntu17.04_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package timedoctorlite.
(Reading database ... 214828 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../timedoctorlite_2.3.49-15ubuntu17.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking timedoctorlite (2.3.49-15ubuntu17.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of timedoctorlite:
 timedoctorlite depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not installed.
 timedoctorlite depends on libcv2.4; however:
  Package libcv2.4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package timedoctorlite (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 timedoctorlite
```

Comment: We could possibly help more if you provided the command used to install, plus errors you got on install (copy & paste output please into question).  I don't see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=yimedoctor or https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=timedocyor  (are your two package names correct!??)

Comment: Is it TimeDoctor that you are looking for?  If so, that is third party and not in the repositories.  https://www.timedoctor.com/help/how-to-install-time-doctor-on-linux-ubuntu-17.10

Comment: I have changed question description . I know every new product has own bugs or defects. Please fix bugs on the bionic beaver.

Comment: I know this  software is third party but it requirs some linux packages and I have installed them but unfortunately have not installed all packages. For example libxss1,libxmu and libcv2.4. I think problem with media packages, opnecv  too.

Comment: `Package gksu is not installed.` This is because **`gksu` is deprecated and no longer available (in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)**. Maybe your program package will work in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, you can try that.

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev did you find solution of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment but I have resolved this issue after a day of fiddling. I was trying to install Time Doctor Pro on Ubuntu 18 LTS, and the issue is it doesn't sync but solved it finally.

@madzohan the reason Time Doctor Pro doesn't sync is that it cannot establish an SSL Connection to the Time Doctor server. You would see this error if you run `./timedoctor` in the terminal.

I tried installing `libssl-dev` but it didn't make a difference. Dug deep on other forums on how to resolve the SSL issue and tried every suggestion I come across.

The solution is to install `libssl1.0-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Note that it will remove other libssl related packages. After that, your Time Doctor Pro should work as intended.

You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 18.04 there is no version of Time Doctor.

[Instruction](https://enbravikov.wordpress.com/2018/09/15/how-to-install-time-doctor-on-ubuntu-18-04/) below shows how to install Time Doctor for Ubuntu 16.04 on Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Add repositories of Ubuntu 16.04. Create and open the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu16_04.list` file by followed command:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu16_04.list
   ```
2. Put the following list of repositories into the file:

   ```
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
   deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
   ```
3. Save the file via Ctrl+O and close its via Ctrl+X.
4. Update the list of packages:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Install dependencies of Time Doctor:

   ```
   sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libssl1.0.0 libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns gksu gdebi libjpeg8 libpng12-0 libcv2.4 libxcb-record0
   ```
6. Download Time Doctor for Ubuntu 16.04 from [official page](https://www.timedoctor.com/download.html).
7. Install the downloaded package (file name may differ):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i timedoctorlite_2.3.49-14ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
   ```
8. Run Time Doctor and check how its work. You may use command line (example for the Lite version):

   ```
   timedoctorlite
   ```
9. Restore the initial state of packages in the system:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu16_04.list
   sudo apt update
   ```
10. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The .deb package you tried to install depends on packages which are not available on 18.04. `gksu` might have been easy to work around, but `libcv2.4` is a stopper. If Time Doctor Lite is important to you, please use Ubuntu 16.04 instead whose archive includes both those packages.

*Time Doctor Pro* might be an alternative.

Comment: Time Doctor Pro installs but doesn't sync